# Calling volatile member function using not volatile object in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, volatile, member-functions

What happens, If calling **volatile member function** using **not volatile object**?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A 
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    void func(int a) volatile //volatile function
    {
        x = a;
        cout<<x<<endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    A a1; // non volatile object
    a1.func(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will be called normally.

Comment: Nice phrasing to avoid [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826719/c-volatile-member-functions), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746070/what-does-it-mean-when-a-member-function-is-volatile), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444734/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-volatile-member-function-in-c) being an exact dupe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule is same as `const` member function. A `volatile` member function could be called on a non-`volatile` object, but a non-`volatile` member function couldn't be called on a `volatile` object.

For your case, `A::func()` will be invoked fine. If you make them opposite, the compilation would fail.

```
class A 
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    void func(int a) // non-volatile member function
    {
        x = a;
        cout<<x<<endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    volatile A a1;   // volatile object
    a1.func(10);     // fail
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call it just  like a `const` function on a non-const object, but for different reasons.

The `volatile` qualifier makes the implicit this parameter be treated as a pointer to a volatile object.

Essentially, this means that the semantics of volatile objects will be applied when accessing the data member(s) of the object. Any read of `x` cannot be optimized away, even if the compiler can prove there is no recent write after the last read.

Naturally, if the object isn't really volatile the body of `func` is still correct, albeit not as optimized as it can be. So you can call it just fine.